# PNACL – using winscard lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I’m developing Portable Native Client application which works with the smart card. For this purpose, I want to include winscard library to my project. 
Currently I failed at the stage of compilation.

I added a line in my source file

```
#include <winscard.h>
```

and the path in Additional Include Directories

> C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft SDKs \ Windows \ v7.1A \

I received an error

> C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft SDKs \ Windows \ v7.1A \ Include
>   \ windows.h (151,10): fatal error: 'excpt.h' file not found

Then I added a path to excpt.h

> C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 \ VC \ include

and I received the following error

> 1>  chromesign.cc 1> 
>   C:\Dev\Lib\nacl_sdk\vs_addin\examples\chromesign\In file included from
>   chromesign.cc(27): 1> 
>   C:\Dev\Lib\nacl_sdk\pepper_43\include\ppapi\cpp\instance.h(11):'In
>   file included from C'  1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\VC\include\map(6):'In file included from C'  1> 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\xtree(6):'In file included from C'  1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(6):'In
>   file included from C'  1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstdlib(5):'In file included from C'  1> 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\yvals.h(6):'In file included from C'  1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(44,2):
>   error : ERROR: Only Win32 target supported! 1>NACLCOMPILE : #error
>   error : Only Win32 target supported!

Does anyone know how to fix this error or another way to use winscard lib in PNACL application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windows.h` is a Windows-specific header. PNaCl doesn't support such headers because it has to be portable and work across operating systems while securing users from malicious / buggy `.pexe` files.

winscard itself is Windows specific, and will not work either. There are [proposals](http://www.w3.org/2012/webcrypto/webcrypto-next-workshop/papers/W3C_HID_Global_Submission.html) to make smart card access from the browser possible. I recommend looking there first. The answer to your question: this cannot work as-is in PNaCl.

You can, however, look into using [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) if its restrictions suit your needs.